# apply batch command to google search queries in multiple txt files

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to copy google queries from multiple txt files located in a folder, and search each of them in separate google tab using batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\Users\*.txt") do (
  echo %%~A
  start "" msedge.exe www.google.com/search?q="%%~A"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

search.bat

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("C:\Users\Anston Sorensen\Downloads\links.txt") do (
  echo %%~A
  start "" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com/search?q="%%~A"
)
```

queries.txt

```
dog
cat
horse
pig
sheep
```

I use chrome but I just had a file named queries.txt in the same directory. It opened 5 seperate tabs with each of those animals.